# Can we call child component outside parent render function?

Tags: reactjs

Hi I'm new in React is there a way to call child component from parent component outside the render function ?? below is my sudo code,

any idea !!!!!!

```
var Parent React.createClass({

 someFunction: function(){
  //can I call Child component from here on every click
  // as this will rerender  the child component only  on each click
  // leaving parent component unrendered
 }, 

 render: function(){


 }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is `NO`. You've your answer in your question.

Let me explain. A component can be called as a `child` component only if it is used in the `parent` component, meaning, the `child` component should be used inside the `render()` of `parent` component. So, you cannot call a child component out of parent's render.

To achieve you requirement, you can use `state` to re-render the child component.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="example"></div>
<script type="text/babel">

  const Child = React.createClass({
    render() {
      return <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    }
  })

  const Parent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
      return {
        renderChild: false
      }
    },
    onClick(){
      this.setState({
        renderChild: !this.state.renderChild
      })
    },
    render(){
      return <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>{this.state.renderChild ? 'Hide' : 'Show'} Child</button>
        {
          this.state.renderChild &&
          <Child />
        }
      </div>
    }
  })

  ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('example') );
</script>
```